JFrog build info for snapshots not storing timestamp
I am building a maven project and publishing the jfrog build info to artifactory. I am noticing a difference between the path to an artifact in the build info UI vs the path to an artifact in the build info JSON obtained via a REST API call, for SNAPSHOT versions.
When I look at the jfrog build info UI in artifactory I can see an entry for each artifact and a download link to the file in storage.
For example, there are two builds of the project, with links as follows:

build #1: foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ->
snapshots-local/x/y/z/foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-1.0.0-20241212.1.jar
build #2: foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ->
snapshots-local/x/y/z/foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-1.0.0-20241212.2.jar

This is expected.
When I get the build info JSON via the JFrog REST api, however, the info for the artifact includes the non-timestamped -SNAPSHOT path. This means that the path is the same for both builds:
For example, build #1 has the following JSON:
{
  "buildInfo": {
    "name": "foo-ci",
    "number": "1",
    artifacts": [
      {
        "type": "jar",
        "name": "foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
        "path": "snapshots-local/x/y/z/foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
      }
    ]
    ...   

while build #2 has the following JSON:
{
  "buildInfo": {
    "name": "foo-ci",
    "number": "2",
    artifacts": [
      {
        "type": "jar",
        "name": "foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
        "path": "snapshots-local/x/y/z/foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
      }
    ]
    ...   

The path for artifact in the build info JSON is the same "foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" although the download link for the artifict in the build info UI is different "foo-1.0.0-20241212.1.jar" vs "foo-1.0.0-20241212.2.jar".
I would expect that the build info JSON would include the path to the timestamped snapshot file, just as the download link in the UI provides. If there are two snapshot builds and I want to use curl to download the respective files via the path obtained via REST API, then I will get the same file for both builds. This is unexpected.
Is there a way to obtain the build info JSON via the JFrog REST API and determine the correct path for the artifact in both builds?
(yes I know that one should not distinguish -SNAPSHOT artifacts as by definition -SNAPSHOT should resolve to the latest file but there are reasons for inspecting the specific timestamped artifacts in my case)
